# What are the best patterns/designs for stateful API development?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, api

I am about to implement a API for my TCP/IP server written in Java. Right now I have a temporary method that takes a String, executes a command based on the String and returns a String basically like the following.

```
public void communicate(BufferedReader in, PrintWriter out) {
    while(true) {
        out.println(handleCommand(in.readLine()));
    }
}

private String handleCommand(String command) {
    if (command.equals("command1") {
        // do stuff
        return "Command 1 executed";
    } else if (command.equals("command2") {
        // do some other stuff
        return "Command 2 executed";
    }
}
```

I really want to do something more extensible, smarter and stateful, so I could handle more complex and stateful commands and without the method/class getting bloated.

How would you start?

Suggestions, ideas, or links for further reading are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using an interface, such as:

```
interface Command {
   public boolean doCommand();
}

enum CommandNames {
   COMMAND1("COMMAND1"),
   COMMAND2("COMMAND2");

   // other enum stuff

   // Gets a command based on a name
   public static CommandNames getCommand(String name);
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<CommandNames, Command> commands;

private String handleCommand(String command) {
   Command command = commands.get(CommandNames.getCommand(command));

   command.handleCommand();
}
```

First draft, but it ought to at least give you some ideas.

Comment: Enums looks like a good way to go, thank you very much for your suggestion, very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest one is thread-per-connection. With flow like:

```
while (true) {
    accept a connection ;
    create a thread to deal with the client ;
end while
```

That's good enough even for relatively high traffic.

For *extreme* performance under very high traffic, you'd rather need event-driven/asynchronous server. These tend to be more complicated, so in that case I'd recommend you to base your solution on existing one, like [JBoss' **Netty**](http://www.jboss.org/netty) or [Apache **MINA**](http://mina.apache.org/). Just that you get idea of the performance here, event-driven servers we're designed to combat the [**C10K problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) (10,000+ concurrent client connections).

Comment: I was rather looking for a smarter API (command handling) implementation. I already have the code for handling the connection initialization. But thanks for you answer :)

Comment: I guess I've focused too much on the word "pattern" in title ;-)